# gruntjs: Configure which files to concat from command line

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

In my project I have JS-files-modules that should be packed in one file.

Folder structure:

```
| src
| - start.js
| - module1.js
| - module2.js
| - module3.js
| - end.js
```

I want to configure which modules to include in file from command line.

For example, if I run `grunt -module1-module3`, generated file should be made of start.js, module1.js, module3.js, end.js.

Is there a built in support for this? Or maybe is there any plugin that can help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a comma separated list of files from which you can build a files object. Here's a quick example:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  function buildFiles() {
    var buildFiles = grunt.option('build-modules').split(',');
    buildFiles.unshift('start');
    buildFiles.push('end');
    for (var i = 0, l = buildFiles.length; i < l; i += 1){
      buildFiles[i] = buildFiles[i] + ".js";
    }
    return buildFiles;
  }

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
   concat: {
      dist: {
        src: buildFiles(), 
        dest: 'dist/out.js'
      }
    },
  });

};
```

You can call grunt with: `grunt concat --build-modules=module1,module2`